# Unable to select spring batch job to run with spring.batch.job.names options

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I have a spring batch code base that has multiple `Job` beans defined within its `BatchConfig`. I've got auto-run disabled with `spring.batch.job.enabled=false` in the correct spot. The basic outline is like:

My batch config looks like this:

```
@Configuration
public class BatchConfiguration {

  @Autowired
  public JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

  @Autowired
  public StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;

  @Bean
  public Job myTestJob1() {...}

  @Bean
  public Job myTestJob2() {...}

}
```

Main class is:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
public class BatchProcessingApplication {

  public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    System.exit(SpringApplication.exit(SpringApplication.run(BatchProcessingApplication.class, args)));
  }
}
```

When I try to run the jar like this, it will start up successfully and exit without running a job:

`java -jar batch.jar -spring.batch.job.names=myTestJob1`

As far as I can tell, this *should* be working, yet it's not. I've tried moving the @EnableBatchProcessing to the BatchCongfig class and it also doesn't work.

Comment: Setting spring.batch.job.enable=false disables the BatchAutoConfiguration JobLauncherApplicationRunner configuration which uses the spring.batch.job.names property to determine what jobs to run. Take a look at the first Bean configured here: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/main/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/batch/BatchAutoConfiguration.java

Answer (score 0):

Please use:
`java -jar batch.jar --spring.batch.job.names=myTestJob1`

Answer (score 0):

You're using this command:

```
java -jar batch.jar -spring.batch.job.names=myTestJob1
```

According to Spring documentation for [Running from the Command Line](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto.html#howto.batch.running-from-the-command-line):

> *Spring Boot converts any command line argument starting with -- to a property to add to the Environment, see accessing command line properties. This should not be used to pass arguments to batch jobs.*

In order for Spring to "see" what you're asking it to do, you need to change from this:

```
java -jar batch.jar -spring.batch.job.names=myTestJob1
```

to this:

```
java -jar batch.jar --spring.batch.job.names=myTestJob1
```

The only difference is using "`--`" as prefix to "spring.batch.job.names" (and not single dash: "`-`").